# Why am I getting "Navigation timeout is disabled when remote debugging is enabled" error message from Headless Chrome?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am trying to run Headless Chrome from Puppeteer but I get "Navigation timeout is disabled when remote debugging is enabled." error message from **Chrome** if I use --timeout flag with --remote-debugging-address.

Not sure why this is the case, does anyone know ?

```js
 args: ['--timeout=60000',
            '--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0',
            '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--enable-logging']
```

That argument is passed into puppeteer.launch(arguments);

Comment: That seems to be the chromium issue not puppeteer: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/app/headless_shell.cc?rcl=eea5bb2772e9aa34bcbf91ded3bca249e94f737d&l=208

Comment: @mbit that is correct. however i still don’t know why that would be the case. I couldn’t find any documentation on it as well. Please share any info you might have on this ;)

Comment: My understanding is it's an either or option, which makes sense. meaning either set it from command line or use `--remote-debugging-port` and send the devtools commands. take a look at this code review discussion: https://codereview.chromium.org/2609843002

Comment: that is what i have been doing. i have been using args only. this error is related to —timeout=6000 for some reason i can change the timeout and enable remote debugging. not sure why.

Comment: you're setting both from the command line which creates an issue. can you try setting timeout using `await page.setDefaultTimeout(60000)` instead?

Comment: I am actually not doing that. Like I tried running Chromium in headless mode passing in the same arguments in shell and got the same error message. This is even before using Puppeteer at all.

Comment: This is a feature not a bug. as I mentioned you can't (and shouldn't be able to) pass both of the arguments at the same time. if you want to know why read the previous comment or the code review discussion.